# Articles in proverbs

Tags: articles

Why is "It's **THE** early bird that catches **THE** worm
and why is "**A** drowning man will clutch at **A** straw"
I just can's the logic here. Would someone explain me?

Comment: A drowning man isn't all that particular.

Comment: (And can you explain the meaning of "can's" to me?)

Comment: mistype. I meant "can't".

Comment: but i can't understand exactly why the early bird is that particular...

Comment: wikipedia.com could give you nice explanations of each.

Comment: I understand meanings of proverbs. I don't understand why is there THEs in the first one.

Comment: "... can't the logic here" makes no sense.

Comment: Do understand that largely it's just a matter which form gained popularity first.  (But there is a certain logic to it, though it's subtle.)

Comment: can't see the logic. did you really didn't understand? lol.

Comment: maybe there is 'the' because the proverb is addressed to a specific person?

Comment: Please understand that "explain me" is ungrammatical. Unlike *tell*, there is no possibility of dative alternation with *explain*. It must be *explain it to me* or *explain to me what you mean*.

Comment: in retro ... this ? could have been migrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a mistake to over-analyse the precise wording of proverbs. They are set phrases that have been repeated so often that everybody knows them. It is a matter of chance what wording has survived that process. One could invent proverbs with the opposite wording:

1. A sleepless bird can choose a tasty morsel.
2. The weaker swimmer makes the bigger splash.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not sure the second example you gave is good. You anyway CAN'T say "A weakest".

Comment: OK. Edited to avoid this criticism.